# Replace Regex match

Tags: c#, replace

I have this string:

```
string coordinates = @"=ZS123, ZS1234 + 36 + Z(56)S45 + 0";
```

This string must be converted to another string, depending on the values. The regex finds the values I need to make calculations. Regex matches following values: ZS123, ZS1234, Z(56)S45

```
Regex regexPattern1 = new Regex(@"(Z.*?S(?:\([^)]+\))?(?:\d+)?)");
string coordinates = @"=ZS123, ZS1234 + 36 + Z(56)S45 + 0";
MatchCollection matchCollection = regexPattern1.Matches(coordinates);
        
//Piece by piece the coordinates are replaced by other strings, after a calculation has been done with the matched string
foreach (Match match in matchCollection)
{
    if (match.Value.StartsWith("ZS("))
    {
        //calculations
        string cellIndex =  XY //output 
        coordinates = coordinates.Replace(match.Value, cellIndex);

        //the Match should be replaced with the calculated value(cellindex)
        //but of course this leads to a problem by doing it this way
        // my coordinates string would be now
        //coordinates = XY, XY4 + 36 + Z(56)S45 + 0";
        //it should be:
        //coordinates = XY, ZS1234 + 36 + Z(56)S45 + 0";
        //how to replace the exact match at the right spot once?
    }
    else if (match.Value.StartsWith("Z(") && match.Value.Contains("S("))
    {
        //calculations
        string cellIndex = //output 
        coordinates = coordinates.Replace(match.Value, cellIndex);
    }

   //////else if()
   //////
}
```

I am a novice in programming, thanks a lot for your help. I hope this is so far understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Regex.Matches()`, you should use an overload of the [`Regex.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace) method that takes a [`MatchEvaluator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator) argument so that you can do your "calculations" in the method of the MatchEvaluator.

Your code should look something like this:

```
Regex regEx = new Regex(@"(Z.*?S(?:\([^)]+\))?(?:\d+)?)");
string coordinates = @"=ZS123, ZS1234 + 36 + Z(56)S45 + 0";

string output = regEx.Replace(coordinates, delegate (Match m)
{
    string cellIndex = m.Value;
    if (m.Value.StartsWith("ZS("))
    {
        //calculations
        cellIndex = "Something";
    }
    else if (m.Value.StartsWith("Z(") && m.Value.Contains("S("))
    {
        //calculations
        cellIndex = "Something else";
    }
    // etc.

    return cellIndex;
});
```

Note that I didn't make any changes to your regex pattern because you haven't provided enough information about what should and shouldn't match. However, let me point something out...

The `Z.*?S` part will match any number of characters (any characters) between "Z" and "S". So, it will match things like "ZA1@S". It's also the part that is responsible for matching "Z(56)S" in your third expected match and the `(?:\([^)]+\))?` part is irrelevant here. If your original intention was to only allow parentheses between "Z" and "S", then you probably should use something like the following instead:

```
Z(?:\([^)]+\))?S(?:\d+)?
```

Another note is that you might want to review your `if` conditions as they don't really make sense based on your expected matches. *I.e., none of the matches starts with "ZS(" or both starts with "Z(" and contains "S(".*

Comment: thats exactly what i need, works perfect!! regex is fine for my purpose, but thanks anyway for your time!